# Error with sychronizing gradle project

Tags: import, gradle, libgdx, project

So i was using Eclipse for JAVA programming all the time and now i had to switch to Android Studio.

I made a new libgdx project with libgdx version **1.5.3.**
When i tried to import the project into Android Studio it automatically started sync it and after a while it showed an error in Messages Gradle Sync: **Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.**

How can I configure the proxy settings?

*P.S.
I am using Android Studio verison 1.0.2*